# Upgrading to Spring boot 2.1.0 Data Jpa + Batch, encountering ORA-00942

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am encountering an issue with upgrading to spring boot 2.1.0 respectively, i am using jpa + hibernate & my entities and repositories are simple ones.

Basically my code is working on spring boot 2.0.4 but when upgrading 2.1.0 *(No code changes done)* my repositories are throwing **ORA-00942** errors. I checked the hibernate queries on both version and they all look the same.

I have read the [changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes) and i dont see anything that might have caused the issue.

I am stumped with this issue any suggestions are welcome!

**Errors & setup that i have are below**

Repository setup:

```
package com.my.sample.app.dao

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {
     MyEntity findTopByTypeOrderByStartTimeDesc(String type);
}
```

JPA Related Configs:

```
package com.my.sample.app.configs

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", basePackages = "com.my.sample.app.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConnectionConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");

        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.my.sample.app.entity").persistenceUnit("my-jpa").properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "myJpaTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
package com.my.sample.app.entity

@Entity
@Table(name = "AUDIT_TABLE")
public class AuditLog implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7862607645530582453L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    @Column(name = "AUDIT_ID")
    private String auditId;
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String dataType;
    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;
    @Column(name = "END_TIME")
    private Date endTime;
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Errors encountered:

```
2018-11-30 14:37:04.539  WARN 21616 --- o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  : SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
2018-11-30 14:37:04.539 ERROR 21616 --- o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Properties file:

```
my-datasource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/service
my-datasource.username = username
my-datasource.password = password
my-datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

**PS: The table does definitely exist and my code works on spring boot 2.0.4 version. Not sure what broke when upgrading to 2.1.0**

Comment: Can you also add the properties file?

Comment: Have added the properties file, the setup have been changed accordingly to not show real values.

Comment: Do you use @JpaProperties annotation?

Comment: Between 2.0.4 and 2.1.0 the hibernate version changed from 5.2 -> 5.3. Check Hibernate's migration guide if there is anytihing Oracle related.

Comment: Hi guys, i found out the issue that i was just connecting to a wrong database due to a duplicate properties file in my classpath. After cleaning up the job is working fine. NO issues when upgrading from 2.0.4 to 2.1.0 whatsoever, the weird thing only was that how was the classpath search happening between spring 2.0.4 & 2.1.0 when the same setup is present on both?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change your Properties file to:**

```
my-datasource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:service
```